# weblogic cluster context

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, cluster-computing, weblogic-10.x, servletcontextlistener

I have a web service app running on WebLogic 10.3.  Recently, I created a cluster so the app would run on multiple servers and share resources.  I have a `ServletContextListener` to which I bind/unbind properties/objects at server startup/shutdown.

With a single server, this works great.  However, in the cluster, when one server goes down, the context listener (`contextDestroyed` method) is invoked and everything is unbound from the context (the other servers can no longer use the resources then).  Is there another listener I could use or is there a way to run the `contextDestroyed` method only when the last server in the cluster is being shutdown?

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm kinda new to WebLogic and Java EE in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [SingletonService](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/clusters/ConfigureSingletonService.html) for controlling the resources on a cluster